# Can login with attemptLoginWithUserName: on Simulator, but not on iPhone

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

I have a strange problem. After I logged in with the standard SPLoginViewController, I save the username and the credential. After I startup again, I try to call:

> [[SPSession sharedSession] attemptLoginWithUserName:
>   existingCredential:

On the iOS Simulator (iOS 6.0), it works just fine. On my iPhone (iOS 6.0.1), it does not. SPSession is logging in exactly five minutes after I called the attemptLogin method. SPSession is also logging in when I put my app in the background.

Does anyone know more about this and maybe a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's a known bug in libspotify where sp_session_process_events() will sometimes return excessively high values in next_timeout.  I've seen values such as 300100 and 300195 come out of the routine.

One workaround is to set your wait to the max of next_timeout and 50.  (Or 100 or whatever your heart desires.)  See https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/issues/140

I wish Spotify would start a known-issues list for libspotify.  I wasted over a day trying to dig this one out.  Hopefully this post will save someone else the same fate.